# Find out if a directory exists in php

Tags: php, mkdir, chdir

I want to know whether or not a directory exists.

If not, I would like to create the directory.

My code is below:

```
$da = getdate();
$dat = $da["year"]."-".$da["mon"]."-".$da["mday"];
$m = md5($url)."xml";
if(is_dir($dat))
{
    chdir($dat);
    $fh = fopen($m, 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $xml); 
    fclose($fh);
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    mkdir($dat,0777,true); 
    chdir($dat);   
    $fh = fopen($m, 'w');   
    fwrite($fh, $xml);    
    fclose($fh); 
    echo "not";
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't post the full question the first time?

Comment: somebody cant understand what i am saying?
that y  i am putting code?
do u have any problem for putting code....

Comment: Of course not. I'm just curious as to why your question started out so  vague. I suspect some people would have answered differently had you posted your code first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`is_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php), which checks whether the path exists *and* is a directory then [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

```
function mkdir_if_not_there($path) {
  if (!is_dir($path)) {
    // Watch out for potential race conditions here
    mkdir($path);
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to check the folder s exist or not...

please see my coding...

i will just update...

Comment: Err... what? That's what my function does!

Answer (score 0):

Use is_dir:

```
$pathname = "/path/to/dir";
if(is_dir($pathname)) {
   // do something
}
```